# ¿Cómo hacer que un rectángulo se mueva de lado a lado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Para un juego que estoy desarrollando necesito hacer que un rectángulo se mueva de lado a lado, en este caso concreto quisiera que el sprite `rect1` tuviera este comportamiento. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Aquí dejo el código que tengo:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint
import time


ancho = 700
alto = 640

negro = (0,0,0)
blanco = (255,255,255)

class Stanly(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/Stanly.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 50
        self.rect.centery = 580

        self.vel = 1

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += self.vel
        if self.rect.bottom > 640:
            self.rect.bottom = 640

        if keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= self.vel
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0

        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += self.vel
        if self.rect.right > 700:
            self.rect.right = 700

        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= self.vel
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

class rectU(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/ud.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 0
        self.rect.top = 0  
class rectD(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/ud.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 0
        self.rect.top = 608
class rectL(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/lr.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 0
        self.rect.top = 0
class rectR(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/lr.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.right = 700
        self.rect.top = 0

class rect1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/rect 1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 72
        self.rect.bottom = 640

class rect2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/rect 1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 144
        self.rect.top = 0
class rect3(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/rect 1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left =  216
        self.rect.bottom = 640
class rect4(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/rect 1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 288
        self.rect.top = 0
class rect5(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/rect 1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 360
        self.rect.bottom = 640
class rect6(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/rect 1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 432
        self.rect.top = 0
class rect7(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/rect 1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 504
        self.rect.bottom = 640
class rect8(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/rect 1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 576
        self.rect.top = 0        


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
rects = pygame.sprite.Group()
Mrects = pygame.sprite.Group()
players = pygame.sprite.Group()


def Game():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1,25)

    ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ancho, alto))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

    player = Stanly()

    RectU = rectU()
    RectD = rectD()
    RectL = rectL()
    RectR = rectR()
    Rect1 = rect1()
    Rect2 = rect2()
    Rect3 = rect3()
    Rect4 = rect4()
    Rect5 = rect5()
    Rect6 = rect6()
    Rect7 = rect7()
    Rect8 = rect8()

    all_sprites.add(player)


    all_sprites.add(RectU)
    all_sprites.add(RectD)
    all_sprites.add(RectL)
    all_sprites.add(RectR)

    # rects level 1
    all_sprites.add(Rect1)
    all_sprites.add(Rect2)
    all_sprites.add(Rect3)
    all_sprites.add(Rect4)
    all_sprites.add(Rect5)
    all_sprites.add(Rect6)
    all_sprites.add(Rect7)
    all_sprites.add(Rect8)

    rects.add(RectU)
    rects.add(RectD)
    rects.add(RectL)
    rects.add(RectR)

    # rects level 1
    rects.add(Rect1)
    rects.add(Rect2)
    rects.add(Rect3)
    rects.add(Rect4)
    rects.add(Rect5)
    rects.add(Rect6)
    rects.add(Rect7)
    rects.add(Rect8)

    players.add(player)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        colls = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(players, rects, False, False)
        for player, rects_ in colls.items():
            player.rect.centerx = 50
            player.rect.centery = 580

        # Actualizamos todos los sprites del juego
        all_sprites.update()
        ventana.fill(negro)
        # Dibujamos todos los sprites     
        all_sprites.draw(ventana)
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

Game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es que el sprite se desplace de lado a lado de la pantalla (o de un espacio determinado) constantemente, simplemente debes especificar una velocidad de desplazamiento, sobreescribir su método `update` para que en cada iteración modifique sus coordenadas en el eje *X* de acuerdo a la velocidad e invertir el signo de la velocidad cuando llegue a alguno de los límites para que invierta la dirección del desplazamiento.

Simplificando tu código para que sea más fácil de reproducir podemos crear el siguiente ejemplo:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


ANCHO = 700
ALTO = 640
NEGRO = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 60


class Rect1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rect1, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/rect 1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = ALTO
        self.vel = 150

    def update(self, dt):
        self.rect.left += round(self.vel*dt)

        if self.rect.right > ANCHO or self.rect.left < 0:
            self.vel *= -1


def game():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 25)

    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO, ALTO))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
    fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    rect1 = Rect1()
    all_sprites.add(rect1)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        dt = fps_clock.tick(FPS) / 1000.0
        all_sprites.update(dt)
        ventana.fill(NEGRO)
        all_sprites.draw(ventana)
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

Obtenemos el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por si alguien quiere reproducir fácilmente el código dejo la imagen usada para el sprite, que debe ser guardada en una carpeta llamada ***sprites*** situada en el directorio de nuestro script:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

***Una observación en cuanto a la velocidad de movimiento del sprite:***

Con el fin de que la velocidad de movimiento de los sprites no dependa de los fotogramas por segundo (que pueden variar tanto especificándolos de forma explícita como por la capacidad del hardware) se suele normalizar usando como unidad `pixeles/segundo`. En este caso el sprite se mueve a 150 pixeles cada segundo.

Para conseguir lo anterior lo que hacemos es pasarle al método `update` de cada sprite los segundos que pasaron desde que el último fotograma fue dibujado. Lo cual conseguimos con `dt = fps_clock.tick(FPS) / 1000.0`. Todos los sprites del grupo reciben el parámetro dt, por lo que todos sus métodos `update` deben aceptarlo (`def update(self, dt)`). Se puede comprobar como la velocidad es constante independientemente de los fps modificando la constante `FPS`.

---

Independientemente ya de la pregunta, te recomiendo mirarte las convenciones sobre estilo del código definidas en [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) cuando tengas tiempo. Aunque son solo eso, convenciones, ayudan a que tu código siga un estándar y por tanto a su legibilidad por terceros. Por ejemplo, las clases deben nombrarse empezando por mayúscula y usando CamelCase, las funciones deben ser en minúscula y usando subrayado para separar palabras, las constantes deben ir en mayúsculas y usando subrayado para separar palabras, etc.